# PLSQL how to store a result of a select statement

Tags: plsql, plsqldeveloper

I need to delete data from many tables based on one parameter

The problem is that two tables are related to each other so in order to delete data properly i need to store id's somewhere.

```
-- i would like to store temp data
-- this one is only for convienience to avoid repeating same select many times
create table ztTaryfa as select zt_taryfa from tw_zbiory_taryfy 
where 1=2;
-- this one is mandatory but I dont know how to make it work
Create table wnioskiId as select poli_wnio_id_wniosku from polisy 
where 1=2;


Begin

-- fill temp tables  
insert into ztTaryfa (
    select zt_taryfa from tw_zbiory_taryfy 
    where zt_zbior = :zbiorId);

  insert into wnioskiId (
    select poli_wnio_id_wniosku from polisy 
    where poli_taryfa_id in ztTaryfa);

  - regular deletion
  delete from POLISY_OT where ot_poli_id in (
    select poli_id from polisy 
    where poli_taryfa_id in ztTaryfa);
  commit;

  delete from DANE_RAPORTOWE where DR_RPU_ID in ( 
    select RPU_ID from ROZLICZ_PLIK_UBEZP where RPU_ROZLICZ_PLIK_ID in (
    select RP_ID from ROZLICZ_PLIK 
    where RP_ZBIOR_ID = :zbiorId ));
  commit;

  -- and here we go I need to delete data from POLISY first
  delete from POLISY where poli_taryfa_id in ztTaryfa;
  commit;

  -- but by doing it I lose ids which i need here, 
  -- so I have to store them somehow and use them here.
  delete from WNIOSKI where wnio_id in wnioskiId;
  commit;

End;

-- and now lets get rid off temp tables
drop table ztTaryfa;
commit;
drop table wnioskiId;
commit;
```

To sum up i just need to know how to store somewhere between Begin and End a result of a select query which I can later use in delete statement. 
Sounds but I tried so many different methods and all seems to not work.

What u see above is just a 1/3 of the script so I rly would like to make it all simple to use with one parameter.

Thanks you in advance.

Comment: Read the fine manual: [Query Result Set Processing With SELECT INTO Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/static.htm#LNPLS551).

Answer (score 0):

You can use global types as simple as this:

```
create or replace type myrec  is object (myid number);
create or replace type mytemp_collection is table of myrec;

declare 

  v_temp_collection mytemp_collection;
begin
  v_temp_collection  := mytemp_collection();

  select myrec (t.field_type_id ) bulk collect into v_temp_collection from fs_field_types t 
  where mod(t.field_type_id+1,3)=0; -- for example
  FOR i IN 1 .. v_temp_collection.count LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(v_temp_collection(i).myid);
  End loop;  

 delete fs_field_types_back t where t.field_type_id in (select myid from table(v_temp_collection));


end;
```

Change select and where clause according to your business.